# How to get 4-character codec code for VideoCapture object in OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

How do you retrieve the four-character codec code from a `VideoCapture` object in `OpenCV 4`? When I try to inspect it I get a float:

```
import cv2

movie_name = 'fubar.mp4'
movie = cv2.VideoCapture(movie_path)
codec_code =  movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
print(codec_code)
```

This prints out something like `828601953.0`. There are lots of threads about how to *create* a codec code, but I haven't found any on how to extract and read one out from an arbitrary `VideoCapture` object in Python.

I know the name of the file is informative (`mp4`) but that doesn't really specify the exact four-character encoding that I'm after (say, if I want to resave as a new movie after some processing, or just display the code to the user as metadata).

**Related Thread**
There is a thread on how to do this in C++ if anyone can translate to Python that would be the answer I suppose:
[Qt or OpenCV: print out the codec of a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108298/qt-or-opencv-print-out-the-codec-of-a-video-file?rq=1)

Comment: you could try assigning it to a 32 bit int and afterwards read/access all 4 bytes individually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
hex(int(828601953.0))
```

prints:

```
'0x31637661'
```

Now do `man ascii` to get an ASCII table and look up the hex:

```
31 = 1
63 = c
76 = v
61 = a
```

So your FOURCC is `avc1`.

Not sure if there's a better way in Python, but this seems ok:

```
h = int(828601953.0)
chr(h&0xff) + chr((h>>8)&0xff) + chr((h>>16)&0xff) + chr((h>>24)&0xff)
```

prints:

```
'avc1'
```

Comment: This seems promising, but how does that second half work in Python?

Comment: I have updated it. There may be better ways, but I am no expert.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847673/fast-way-to-split-an-int-into-bytes

Comment: @MarkSetchell that is clever I like it. Will test it with a few movies just to make sure but it seems to work!

Comment: I like that you figured this out yourself, but unfortunately this solution suffers from an endianness bug. I've posted my own solution below which can run on any computer.

Answer (score 2):

## Python bytes

```
>>> import sys
>>> int(828601953).to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder).decode()
'avc1'
```

That is all you need, but read on if you'd like to understand how it works.

### Details

Python has a builtin type called `bytes` which makes parsing the FOURCC code trivial. Let's expand the above solution to make each step more clear:

```
>>> h = int(828601953)
>>> b = h.to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
>>> s = b.decode()
>>> s
'avc1'
```

### Steps

##### 1. Create an integer

Convert your number to an integer, if it isn't already.

```
>>> h = int(828601953)
```

##### 2. Convert the integer to "bytes"

Python integers can be converted into a data type Python confusingly calls "bytes", which are simply streams of 8-bit values. To do the conversion, Python needs to be told how many bytes there are and in what byte order ("big", "little", or sys.byteorder).

While [FourCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC) is defined to be big-endian, Intel processors are *little*-endian and read the bytes backward. This is why the currently accepted answer reverses the order. It is best to not write code that depends upon the endianness of the CPU, so instead we'll use `sys.byteorder` which indicates that Python should use the native byte order of the host.

```
>>> b = h.to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
```

##### 3. Decode the bytes to a string

Once we have a Python bytes object, we simply ask it to decode itself into a string.

```
>>> s = b.decode()
```

##### 4. That is all

Voilà.

```
>>> s
'avc1'
```

### Wrapping it up in a function

Here is a function, inspired by the one written by [@Mikhail-Lobanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838016/5954238).

```py
import sys
def get_fourcc(cap: cv2.VideoCapture) -> str:
    """Return the 4-letter string of the codec the camera is using."""
    return int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))\
             .to_bytes(4, byteorder=sys.byteorder).decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_fourcc(cap: cv2.VideoCapture):
    fourcc = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
    fourcc = bytes([
        v & 255 for v in (fourcc, fourcc >> 8, fourcc >> 16, fourcc >> 24)
    ]).decode()
    return fourcc
```

The answer is based on the **LorenaGdL**'s answer on [OpenCV Forum](https://answers.opencv.org/question/77558/get-fourcc-after-openning-a-video-file/).

Comment: This answer only works on little-endian machines. While that is not a terrible assumption given the prevalence of Intel processors, it is unnecessary. You can use sys.byteorder to find out the native byte order. Please see my answer for details.